# How to fix an upgrade interruption from 10.04 to 10.10?

Tags: 10.04, data-recovery

I was in the process of upgrading from 10.04 to 10.10 via the update manager. In the midst of the installation process, the system lost power. Now when I boot, the login window shows nothing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot into a recovery mode and run the following command,

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
  `sudo apt-get --fix-missing`
  `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: and/or `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: You could also try to reinstall all packages, using `apt-get install --reinstall`.

Answer (score -3):

Probably the best way is to try and upgrade (Via CD) with 11.04. The CD "upgrade" option does not exist for 10.10